# Update/Merge multiple rows with select statement data

Tags: oracle, select, merge, sql-update

Im trying to update a single table with output of a select statement which returns two values. One is the accountid that I need to update in the table, and the other is the information I need to update.

```
Here is my select statement
select CTP.CARETEAMPATIENTID, O.ORGANIZATIONID
  from acts.careteampatient ctp,  
       ods.member m,
       ods.supplierorganization so,
       ods.MASTERSUPPLIERSUPPLIERRELATION mssr,
       ods.INSURANCEORGSUPPLIERRELATION   IOSR, 
       ods.INSURANCEORGANIZATION          IO,
       acts.organization o
where ctp.accountorgid is null
    and m.primarymemberplanid = ctp.primarymemberplanid
    and SO.AHMSUPPLIERID = M.AHMSUPPLIERID
    and mssr.SUPPLIERID       = so.SUPPLIERORGID
    AND iosr.SUPPLIERID       = so.SUPPLIERORGID
    AND io.INSURANCEORGID     = iosr.INSURANCEORGID
    and io.processingmodecd  = 'P'
    and so.usagemnemonic     = 'P'
    and O.ODSACCOUNTID = IO.INSURANCEORGID
    and O.ACCOUNTFLG = 'Y'
```

I want to do something along the lines of

```
update careteampatient
from (select CTP.CARETEAMPATIENTID patientid, O.ORGANIZATIONID orgid
  from acts.careteampatient ctp, 
       ods.member m,
       ods.supplierorganization so,
       ods.MASTERSUPPLIERSUPPLIERRELATION mssr,
       ods.INSURANCEORGSUPPLIERRELATION   IOSR,
       ods.INSURANCEORGANIZATION          IO,
       acts.organization o
where ctp.accountorgid is null
    and m.primarymemberplanid = ctp.primarymemberplanid
    and SO.AHMSUPPLIERID = M.AHMSUPPLIERID
    and mssr.SUPPLIERID       = so.SUPPLIERORGID
    AND iosr.SUPPLIERID       = so.SUPPLIERORGID
    AND io.INSURANCEORGID     = iosr.INSURANCEORGID
    and io.processingmodecd  = 'P'
    and so.usagemnemonic     = 'P'
    and o.odsaccountid = io.insuranceorgid
    and o.accountflg = 'Y') b  
set a.accountorgid = b.orgid
where a.careteampatientid = b.patientid
```

Here is the Merge I also tried

```
merge into careteampatient a
using (select CTP.CARETEAMPATIENTID patientid, O.ORGANIZATIONID orgid
        from acts.careteampatient ctp, 
             ods.member m,
             ods.supplierorganization so,
             ods.MASTERSUPPLIERSUPPLIERRELATION mssr,
             ods.INSURANCEORGSUPPLIERRELATION   IOSR,
             ods.INSURANCEORGANIZATION          IO,
             acts.organization o
      where ctp.accountorgid is null
          and m.primarymemberplanid = ctp.primarymemberplanid
          and SO.AHMSUPPLIERID = M.AHMSUPPLIERID
          and mssr.SUPPLIERID       = so.SUPPLIERORGID
          AND iosr.SUPPLIERID       = so.SUPPLIERORGID
          AND io.INSURANCEORGID     = iosr.INSURANCEORGID
          and io.processingmodecd  = 'P'
          and so.usagemnemonic     = 'P'
          and o.odsaccountid = io.insuranceorgid
          and o.accountflg = 'Y') b
on a.careteampatientid = b.patientid
when matched then
  update 
    set a.accountorgid = b.orgid
```

This isnt working and Im fresh out of ideas, any help would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: I've tried using a `MERGE` and am having the same luck.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was missing brackets on my ON. It should be `on (a.careteampatientid = b.patientid)` also my select should read `select distinct`